# Plotting graphs using R in Jupyter is slow

Tags: r, plot, jupyter

I am plotting heavy graphs in Jupyter using the language R. It is extremely slow as I expect it is first exporting it into EPS and then converting it to a png.

If you try to plot on a native R setup ( R for windows for example ) the plotting is nearly instantaneous.

Is there a way to get R in Jupyter to plot more quickly?

Answer (score 5):

I came here looking for a solution to a potentially related issue-- the browser window became relatively unresponsive with lots of lag when drawing plots with a lot of datapoints, likely because everything was being rendered as vector graphics.

In trying to solve my problem, it sped up initial drawing of graphs by an appreciable amount as well. The solution was to change the jupyter plot output type to png using the command:

```
options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = 'image/png')
```

Now when I plot graphs with 10s of thousands of points, the window remains crisply responsive. The downside is that the plots are now bitmap, but you can always remove the options if you want vector graphics.